# Time.sleep() affecting the code above it in python

Tags: python, user-interface, time, kivy

I am making a KIVY program in python and have a time.sleep(3) in my code so that it waits three seconds before changing the screen. But the function above it works after the 3 seconds and not before it. I am having no errors and I have tried everything but nothing seems to work. 
Here is the snippet.

```
def input_button(self, instance): # creating the button that when pressed updates the label
    query = "You Said {}".format(self.command()) # making the query
    if query == "You Said None":
        self.update_info('Please input a command')
    else:
        self.update_info(query) # updating the label
        time.sleep(3)
        pa_app.screen_manager.current = "Result"
```

The self.update_info(query) runs after three seconds but the time.sleep is after it.

Comment: im not sure what `update_info` info does, but i do want to point out that `sleep` will pause your entire python program, even other threads, so you may be experiencing that

Comment: Please, provide the `update_info` code

Comment: @GabrielMelo `update_info` is a function that updates the label on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using the `from kivy.clock import as Clock` module. I used `Clock.schedule_once` functions and passed `self.change_screen, 10`. I created the `self.change_screen` function as the `Clock.schedule_once` only takes a function and time as the parameters. Although I wanted to wait for 3 seconds, passing 3 in the function didn't make it wait for 3 seconds but less than it. So for having the same effect I passed in 10. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy is a GUI framework and you cannot add sleep statements safely.

when

```
self.update_info(query)
```

is called kivy will update the GUI only after the last line of your function is called, because this is when you give back the control to the Kivy gui engine.

You have to check whether kivy does have timers.
You can start a timer and tell it to call another function that does the

```
pa_app.screen_manager.current = "Result"
```

whenever the timer finished.